Method terminating without exception in C# unity
The method stops working when I call Add(), but there is no exception raised. This is in the Piece class.
protected bool CopyInfoToGlobals()
{
    List<(int x, int y)> ew = range.Keys.ToList();

    print($"dasf  {ew.Count - 1}"); //prints numbers usually above 2

    for (int r = 0; r < ew.Count - 1; r++)
    {
        // prints once correctly
        print($"yfdhg {ew[r].x}, {ew[r].y}");

        // where I think the problem is
        globals.PieceInteractions[ew[r].x, ew[r].y].Add(range[ew[r]]);   
    }

    print("yuo");    // never prints

    return true
}

The second print() should be called several times, but gets called only once. The last print never gets called. This is for chess in unity2d.
When I did this, nothing happens:
if (CopyInfoToGlobals()) 
    print("success at last"); 
else 
    print(32);   // it prints nothing

PieceInteractions declaration in globals which I don't think matters:
public static List<Piece.LocalBoardRepresention>[,] PieceInteractions = new List<Piece.LocalBoardRepresention>[8,8];

What range is:
public Dictionary<(int x, int y),LocalBoardRepresention> range = new Dictionary<(int x, int y), LocalBoardRepresention>(); 

I don't know if this matters either.
public class LocalBoardRepresention 
{
    public Piece @this { get; internal set; }
    public bool r { get; internal set; };
    public bool l { get; internal set; };
    public Piece p { get; internal set; };
}


Any chance this is being called on a background thread/task and an exception is just swallowed? Have you tried Debugging your code and step through it line by line? In general why Count - 1? Do you always want to skip the last item?

Yes u were right there was exeption on that line that only showed when i used the debuggers. also i did count - 1 since it returns the number of indexes starting at 1 when i need at to start a 0. i fixed it now
